# Cloudflare returns SSL 525 error for the domain apex with domain hosted by Blogger even using flexible SSL to the origin

Tags: security-certificate, blogger, cloudflare

When I try to access my blogger using `https://example.com` I get a `525` error, but when I use `https://www.example.com` it works fine. I have changed the SSL/TLS encryption to flexible in Cloudflare but with no luck.

Below are the settings that I am actually using:

Blogger

[image]

Cloudflare

- SSL/TLS encryption mode is Full
- Always Use HTTPS ON
- Opportunistic Encryption ON
- TLS 1.3 ON
- Automatic HTTPS Rewrites ON

ghs.google.com record is DNS ONLY

Comment: `example.com` and `www.example.com` are different domains. An SSL certificate created for `www.example.com` will not work for `example.com` (unless you implement a wildcard or multi-domain/SAN cert).

Comment: Please tell us more about your setup so that this can be re-opened and answered.   How have you configured cloudflare (please include screenshots)?    How have you configured blogger (please include screenshots)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller screenshot and more info added.

Comment: @WarrenHalderman i am using blogger which provides SSL certification automatically. I was thinking that it might be an SSL cert conflict  between Blogger and cloudflare so i have changed SSL encryption to flexible, yet the problem still persists.

Comment: Your DNS for records for `www` and the domain apex are radically different.  for the domain apex you have A records pointing to cloudflare IP addresses.   For `www` you are pointing to Google's server.   Your `www` address doesn't appear to be using Cloudflare at all.  Is that your intention?

Comment: What are your DNS settings in cloudflare?    Which records have cloudflare proxy turned on?

Comment: Thank you all for the great support! Special credit to @WarrenHalderman for his insight about wildcard. i have managed to fix this issue by using page rule in cloudflare by adding *alma3aref.com/. @ StephenOstermiller not at all. my intention was to fix this issue so i have tried several proposals including disabling proxy for ghs.google.com with no luck.  but now everything seems ok. Many thanks guys!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller after enabling proxy on www record for ghs.google.com my home page is no longer accessible and i get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.  i am really lost.

Comment: When you get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error, what is the redirect chain?  I usually test on the command line with `curl --head https://www.example.com/` which shows the `Location: ` header where it is being redirected.   Right now when I test your site I see `200 OK` from your www subdomain and cloudflare as the server.

Comment: i have disabled both redirect domain and https redirect  on Blogger and kept the current settings on cloudflare. after monitoring for 15 minutes it seems fine. this is driving me crazy i have tried these option before and it didn't work, oddly it works now. Anyway, i honestly appreciate your help and insight guys. Many thanks!